# Get top K values in pandas series include recurring values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code snippet in python. It gets top K=5 values but don't increment the value of K if the value has already occurred.

For example upon giving `[1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 1, 4, 8, 9, 34, 66, 124]` and `K = 5`, it should return

`[1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 1, 4]`

Here if a value is repeating then it should not increment the value of K. Here is the Python code. But how can I do it in pandas Series?.

```
def get_top_K_uniques(K, nums):
    ret = []
    presense = defaultdict(bool)
    counter = 0
    for each in nums:
        if not presense[each]:
            presense[each] = True
            counter+=1
        ret.append(each)
        if counter == K:
            return ret
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mad_ I don't need that one. You can read the question again

Comment: Are you look for how to use apply method with series?

Comment: @mad_  No. I need to get the top K unique values but include repeated values while getting the values. You can read the raw python code to understand/

Comment: If you don't want to use lambda just convert your series to list and pass on to your function. It will give what you want. I don't see an issue

Comment: @mad_ I know that but pandas series is better, faster and cleaner.

Comment: Curious what the output you'd want if your input array was reversed.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Series.unique()` and `Series.isin()`

```
nums = pd.Series([1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 1, 4, 8, 9, 34, 66, 124])
uniq = nums.unique()[:5]
nums[nums.isin(uniq)]
```

#### Output

```
0    1
1    3
2    3
3    5
4    5
5    6
6    1
7    4
```

Comment: Adding a new method if you interested . :-)

Comment: It is giving me an error saying list object has no attribute ```isin```. I had nums as pandas series

Comment: I made an explicit construction of the series

Answer (score 1):

Using `category`

```
s[s.astype('category').cat.codes<4]
Out[153]: 
0    1
1    3
2    3
3    5
4    5
6    1
7    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: can you explain how this works, is category autoincremental? this is great!

Comment: @Yuca it freeze all same number to one category , and then we just need to slice the category numbers less than 4 we get all 5 different category